# How to create a FOR loop in BASH that lists files in a certain format

Tags: linux, bash

I want to print all the files in my chosen directory. I want to format the files to be displayed under the column headers. But when I'm trying to run the below code I'm getting errors in the console.

```
list_files()
{   
    FILES=/home/student/.junkdir/
    echo "Listing files in Junk Directory"
    format="%8s%10s%10s   $-s\n"
    printf "$format" "Filename" "Size(Bytes)" "Type"
    printf "$format" "--------" "-----------" "----"
    for listed_file in $FILES; do
        file_name=$(du $listed_file | awk '{print $2}')
        file_size=$(du $listed_file | awk '{print $1}')
        file_type=$(file $listed_file | cut -d ' ' -f2-)
        printf "$format" $file_name $file_size $file_type
    done
}
```

This is the output

```
Listing files in Junk Directory
FilenameSize(Bytes)      Type   hBs
-------------------      ----   hBs
du: cannot access ‘/home/student/.junkdir/*’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/home/student/.junkdir/*’: No such file or directory
ERROR:    cannot      open   hBs
`/home/student/.junkdir/*'       (No      such   hBs
file        ordirectory)   hBs
```

Comment: Did you edit the script when posting it? The error messages lead me to think your for loop is actually `for listed_file in $FILES/*` with a wildcard.

Comment: The directory "/home/student/.junkdir/" exists?

Comment: Yes sorry, my original code had the wildcard. I think I've realised part of my problem.

Comment: See here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/ `FILES` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I didn't actually have any files in the .junkdir yet. Now that I've added the wildcard again, I am getting more success

Comment: @ChrisDaly What do you intend the `$-` part of the format string to do? 'Cause what it's actually doing is listing the shell's options ("bH" - "b" means the status of background jobs will be reported, and "H" means history expansions are enabled).

Comment: I've only taken that part of the code from previous learning materials tbh. Should I just go without it?

Comment: Ok - after having a look again, it should have been a % instead of a $. I'm still learning here lol dont know how that got in there. But now my headings are displaying the way I wan them to. The only problem now is displaying the data.

Comment: If there's the risk of no files, you want to add `shopt -s nullglob` to your script. Otherwise, as you've seen, the pattern does not get substituted with anything and you get the `*: no such file` error

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/stat.1.html) command to get the data, and [`column`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/column.1.html) to make the output pretty.

```
stat -c $'%n\t%s\t%F' * | column -ts $'\t'
```

In a function

```
list_files() {   
    local dir=/home/student/.junkdir/
    echo "Listing files in Junk Directory"
    {
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "Filename" "Size(Bytes)" "Type"
        stat -c $'%n\t%s\t%F' "$dir"/*
    } | column -t -s $'\t'
}
```

Comment: Could you advise how to use this method using the same commands I have in my example? I've tried it myself but not having any joy.

Comment: You only need to call du once: `read -r filesize filename < <(du "$listed_file")`

Comment: files are allowed to have spaces and colons, so I would use substrings to chop off the name from the file output: `output=$(file "$listed_file"); filetype=${output:${#listed_file}+2}`

Comment: The `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). For the substring stuff, see [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)